# illegal character exception in sending data to php from url

Tags: java, php, android, get

when i am appending my data to url and sending it is getting an exception like this:

```
04-03 23:28:24.479      355-355/com.example.smsTest I/System.out﹕ java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 113: http://futuretime.in/login.php?token=DT4XHWPtKnc3l2z4I8n1Y5+li5zh/Yy8AlSC7J9bsjmGnHE8zXJ8Qbb8DwGe+tv93i5COfffsS76
04-03 23:28:24.479      355-355/com.example.smsTest I/System.out﹕ Y4meQzKkbw==
```

Comment: are you stuffing base64-encoded data into the url?

Comment: yes i am using Base64.encodeToString

Comment: you'll have to url-encode that b64-encoded string. b64 includes `+`, which in urls is an encoded space. e.g. your webserver is trashing the b64 string

Comment: i am getting unsupported encoding exception

Comment: thanks got it made urlencoder in try block